# How to format values using SQL in CARTO?

Tags: carto, sql

I am trying to make sense of how to format data values for a popup.

I have values that are reading $890000, and I want them to read $890,000.
How would I format my SQL statement?

More generally, is there documentation on how SQL syntax works in Carto? (I see this symbol | in between statements, and I am trying to understand what that means)

Comment: what are the highest and lowest values in that columns? the sql used in CARTO is anything found in the postgresql sql syntax

Comment: Values range from $0 - $2,234,000.

Comment: Have you tried to apply to_char(<column>,<format>) function  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html to your calculated column?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change all the values in the current column, you can open the SQL window and use this command:

```
update tablename
set dollarvaluecolumn = cast(dollarvaluetable as money)
```

money is a data type used by postgresql, so is usable in CARTO

However, if you want to create a new column and strip the data of the $ sign and convert to integers, you can run this on a new integer column:

```
update tablename
set newdollarvaluecolumn = cast(substring(dollarvaluecolumn from 2) as integer)
```

Comment: The field I am trying to use was field calculated. It is giving me an error when I try to use the first query you wrote. Is there a way to access this field anyway? I wish to use the first query: 

update tablename
set dollarvaluecolumn = cast(dollarvaluetable as money)

Comment: @IsabelleLipton what's the error?

Comment: Syntax error: column "string_sales_vol" does not exist
This field was created from an original field, in order to add a $ at the beginning. 
When I try the query with the original field, I get Syntax error: cannot cast type double precision to money

Comment: I'd say go back to the original field and create a new field that you can update to the original field cast to MONEY type - don't manually add the $ if you can avoid it... does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. From the SQL panel of the `DATA` tab on your BUILDER dashboard modify the `SELECT` statement to create a new virtual field. This is OK if your dataset is not really big and very common approach to create custom values for pop ups. In your case you probably want first need to remove the dollar sign, then format it conveniently, something like

   ```
   SELECT *,
          to_char(
            replace(
              "my_money_field"::text,
              '$',
              ''
            )::bigint,
            '$999,999,999'
          )
     FROM my_table
   ```
2. You can update your current field directly as @DPSSpatial suggested
3. You can create a new column and populate it with the derived value

I would suggest never do 2, so you create a new column if your dataset is big or you know you will use that value for other purposes, or you directly apply a SELECT statement in your dashboard.

CARTO uses PostgreSQL 9.5 so you can follow the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql.html) for more details on the SQL language syntax.